# Pass dynamic values to WSO2 DBLook 'like' query

Tags: mysql, wso2, ei

**Scenario** :
I have used DBLookup mediator to retrieve the full name by passing part of the name. For that I used like option in sql.

> Full Name : John Smith
>
> Value passed : John
>
> SQL : SELECT * FROM table WHERE FullName like '%John%'

**Used config** :

```
    <dblookup>
   <connection>
      <pool>
         <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
         <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world</url>
         <user>root</user>
         <password>root</password>
      </pool>
   </connection>
   <statement>
      <sql>SELECT TP_ID, TP_FULL_NAME, TP_USER_NAME, TP_USER_PASSWORD, TP_ACTIVE, TP_CHANGED_TIME, TP_TENANT_ID FROM tp_user WHERE TP_FULL_NAME like ('%?%');</sql>
      <parameter expression="get-property('name')" type="VARCHAR" />
   </statement>
</dblookup>
```

**Error** :

```
    [2018-11-08 13:04:14,943] [] ERROR - DBLookupMediator SQL Exception occurred while executing statement : SELECT TP_ID, TP_FULL_NAME, TP_USER_NAME, TP_USER_PASSWORD, TP_ACTIVE, TP_CHANGED_TIME, TP_TENANT_ID FROM tp_user WHERE TP_FULL_NAME like ('%?%'); against DataSource : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896151/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-index-out-of-range-1-number-of-parameters-wh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your sql statement as below;

> SELECT TP_ID, TP_FULL_NAME, TP_USER_NAME, TP_USER_PASSWORD, TP_ACTIVE, TP_CHANGED_TIME, TP_TENANT_ID FROM tp_user WHERE TP_FULL_NAME **like CONCAT('%',?,'%')**;

For further reference you can follow this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005251/select-from-tbl-where-clm-like-concat-other-sql-query-limit-1-how)